# How to connect two Hibernate JPA transactions with Spring @Transactional?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-data

In a Spring/Hibernate application two transactions are performed within one method. After the first transaction has been executed and the entity has been saved, the database returns the corresponding id. This id is required for the second entity, which can only then be saved.

```java
@Transactional
public int createAndSaveUser(String username, String email) {

    UserAccountBuilder userAccountBuilder = new UserAccountBuilder(username);
    int id = userAccountBuilder.buildAndSave();

    UserEmailBuilder userEmailBuilder = new UserEmailBuilder(id, email);
    userEmailBuilder.buildAndSave();

    return id;
}
```

The builder are saving the entities by calling the save method of the corresponding JpaRepositories.

Since the id is generated by the database, it is my understanding that the first transaction must be completed in order to get that id. If something goes wrong with the second transaction, then the second transaction is rolled back, but the first transaction is not rolled back, leaving a corpse in the database that has no business being there.

### My question:

How can I undo an already executed transaction in case of an error?

Many thanks for any help

### Edit:

So after some hints from Simon Martinelli and Sven Döring I've played along with multiple possible solutions and stumbled across a mistake that goes on my account:

I call the createAndSaveUser method from outside but within a try-catch-block. And that seems to be the culprit. Annotating the method from which I call createAndSaveUser() also with `@Transactional` makes papa happy again :).

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Your code is correct and should work as expected. Why do you think that the first insert will not be rolledback?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. You get the ID after saving the entity. The transaction can still continue after that. So you have the ID can do your stuff in the second transaction. If that fails you rollback your first transaction.

Comment: So if this code should work, but unfortunately it doesn't, I'll have to figure out where the problem could be. At the moment, in the event of an error, only the second transaction is rolled back. Thanks for the info.